# Umlaut characters using UK keyboard on Windows (no NumPad)

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, special-characters

Several [references](http://www.ukstudentlife.com/Life/Computer/European.htm) describe using <kbd>Alt</kbd> combined with numeric keys (with <kbd>NumLock</kbd> on). Other references suggest using the `United States International` keyboard layout.

But:

- Keyboard is UK (the US layout switches some keys)
- Laptop is a small without a NumPad

Are there other key combinations or can I create key combinations that perform the same thing?

On uBuntu 18.04 the following sequence works (using ü as an example - that was copied from the Windows `Character Map` which is an alternative, though less convenient, option):

- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> (these can be released)
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>"</kbd> (these can be released)
- the character you want an umlaut on ie. <kbd>u</kbd>

This does not work on Windows, although assigning such key combinations on Windows would be great (if this is possible).

Comment: AutoHotKey can probably do this for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the United Kingdom Extended keyboard instead of the US International.

Using UK Extended, to insert an umlaut character, hit <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> then the character (eg. u to ü).

Microsoft Docs has a [keyboard simulator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/keyboards/kbdukx.html) to show what key combinations will give you the various diacritics in UKX.

note: <kbd>AltGr</kbd> is the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to the right of the space bar.

Answer (score 0):

Note on the above answer: hold down <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and press <kbd>2</kbd>, but then RELEASE BOTH and type the vowel <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>, or <kbd>U</kbd> alone. If you are still holding down the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key while typing the vowel, you just get the acute accent - `á` instead of `ä`.

Comment: This could be a.comment on the previous answer, rather than an answer.